# singer recognition/speaker recognition with HTK tool kit

Tags: audio, htk

I am making music retrieval with HTK toolkit

Especially,I would like to make singer recognition.

I think what I want to to do is close to speaker recognition.

SO I researched some samples and red red HTK book.

But still can't find good reference

Is there any good references for singer recognition or speaker recognition?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please be sure to read the FAQ about the type of question that is welcome here.  Summary: programming questions which can be answered with a definitive and authoritative answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the HTK website:
http://www.bas.uni-muenchen.de/Bas/SV/

It uses HTK for speaker identification.

From google:
http://code.google.com/p/sibo-htk/

Luis
ASR Labs
www.asrlabs.com.br

Comment: MASV needs MATLAB.....
SO I have some troubles to execute this.

There is no source code in Sibo-htk.
maybe developpment is cancelled?

Comment: I found this services.
http://www.mobbeel.com/technology/voice/
it might be useful though,I am not sure how it costs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Microsoft Speaker Recognition APIs: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speaker-recognition-api#verification.

You can use the APIs for both verification & identification. Here are their C# & Python SDKs: https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/SpeakerRecognition